# Richfaces 4 - Absolute uri cannot be resolved

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces

I'm trying to implement Richfaces on my project. I've done everything I've found but I can't solve my current problem. At least my Tomcat server starts up, but now the error is as follows (when I load my webpage) (first line is an "absolute uri can't be found" error):

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: La uri absoluta: http://richfaces.org/a4j no puede resolverse o en web.xml o el los archivos jar desplegados con esta aplicación
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:56)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:410)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:117)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl.generateTLDLocation(TagLibraryInfoImpl.java:311)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl.<init>(TagLibraryInfoImpl.java:152)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseTaglibDirective(Parser.java:410)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseDirective(Parser.java:475)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseElements(Parser.java:1425)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:138)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:242)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parse(ParserController.java:102)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:198)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:373)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:353)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:340)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:644)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:358)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:389)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:333)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:684)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:471)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:402)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:329)
    at com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl.dispatch(ExternalContextImpl.java:546)
    at javax.faces.context.ExternalContextWrapper.dispatch(ExternalContextWrapper.java:93)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.JspViewHandlingStrategy.executePageToBuildView(JspViewHandlingStrategy.java:364)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.JspViewHandlingStrategy.buildView(JspViewHandlingStrategy.java:154)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:100)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:410)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:405)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:964)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:515)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:304)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
```

When Tomcat initializes it displays the following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4723)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5226)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5221)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
```

Along with many other errors.

My web.xml is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
        <param-value>server</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>/faces/index.jsf</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.richfaces.skin</param-name>
        <param-value>classic</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.richfaces.enableControlSkinning</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>

</web-app>
```

And my JSF webpage is as follows:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" prefix="f"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" prefix="h"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://richfaces.org/a4j" prefix="a4j"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://richfaces.org/rich" prefix="rich"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<f:view>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
            <title>JSP Page</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1>Hello World!</h1>
            <rich:calendar />
        </body>
    </html>
</f:view>
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: My lib has:

```
richfaces-components-api-4.2.2.Final.jar
richfaces-components-ui-4.2.2.Final.jar
richfaces-core-api-4.2.2.Final.jar
richfaces-core-impl-4.2.2.Final.jar
cssparser-0.9.5.jar
sac-1.3.jar
guava-r08.jar
beanutils, collections, digester and logging libraries from Apache Commons
All basic JSF and JSTL libraries
```

Comment: Have you added all the required libraries to work with RichFaces4? I happened to me when I wanted to start with a RichFaces 4 project. Also, how're you trying to display the page in browser?

Comment: Apparently yes, I edited my post with the libs I imported. Also I'm using /faces/index.jsp to access my page.

Comment: As Luiggi tells, it looks like an issue with classpath. Check that your webapp has access to all of the libraries (usually by putting them in WEB-INF/lib

Comment: I forgot to mention I'm using Netbeans 7, so I guess I have to add them to the Libraries menu on the tree at the left. What's weirder is that I can use JSF normally.

Comment: Right click to your project, go to properties, to build, check that the libraries are in your classpath.

Comment: Well, in Properties -> Libraries I added all the libraries, and JSF is included in the used frameworks alongside Richfaces in Components. In neither of the Build options (Compiling, Packaging, Documenting) I can see my classpath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a matter of fact, my error is that RichFaces 4 doesn't support JSP-like syntax. I tried using Facelets and it worked.